# Liquibase PostgreSql Exception in SQL changeset

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

I am using below sql in my liquibase changset to insert data from another table.

```
  DO $$
  BEGIN
  IF EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
  FROM   information_schema.tables
  WHERE  table_schema = 'test1'
  AND    table_name = 'table1'
  )
  THEN
  INSERT INTO table2(col1, col2, col3, col4)
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
  FROM test1.table1;
  SELECT SETVAL('test_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM test1.table1), 1), FALSE);
  END IF;
  END
  $$;
```

But I am getting below error,

> Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: query has no
> destination for result data\n  Hint: If you want to discard the
> results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

I tried adding a return statement but I get

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: RETURN cannot have a
> parameter in function returning void error

Answer (score 1):

You could try to replace `SELECT` with `PERFORM` when setting the value of the sequence, something like this:

```
PERFORM SETVAL('test_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM test1.table1), 1), FALSE);
```